# Пространство имен в R

Tags: r

Есть ли в R аналог пространства имен как например в PHP:

```
namespace Name;
```

Comment: Не знаю, как в PHP, но звучит вполне похоже на environment? Например, Global Environment или environment конкретной функции. Оно?

Comment: @ikashnitsky на первый взгляд мало общего, но еще почитаю и напишу. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Пространства имён в R реализовано только для пакетов. С некоторыми оговорками в качестве аналога можно использовать окружения, как советовали в комментариях.

```
e <- new.env()
e$fun <- function() 1L
e$var <- 1L
ls.str(e)
#> fun : function ()  
#> var :  int 1
```